# agg(lambda x: ','.join(x.unique())) only provides a few columns, but not all of them

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

After applying groupby, I want to get the unique values of all the columns, but doing `df.groupby(['Query level',"query_type"]).agg(lambda x: ','.join(x.unique()))` does not gives me all the columns.

However, when I do `df.astype(str).groupby(['Query level',"query_type"]).agg(lambda x: ','.join(x.unique()))`, it does give me all the columns.

Why is this happening? Why does the first approach leave out certain columns?

Comment: Because the agg function is applied to each column separately, and the function is only applied to columns where the operation is valid. When you call `df.groupby(['Query level',"query_type"]).agg(lambda x: ','.join(x.unique())),` the `','.join(x.unique())` operation is only applied to columns of a string or object dtype, because the join method can only be called on a sequence of strings. Columns of other `dtypes`, such as numeric or `datetime` columns, are excluded from the result because the operation is not valid for those columns.